# 2 way SSL authentication not working using Apache httpclient: JAVA

Tags: java, apache, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

2 way SSL authentication in JAVA using apache httpclient (certificates are self signed) not working for me. I am getting Bad cert fatal error from Server. I looked at captured pcap in wireshark and I see client is not sending it's certificate. Here is what I have done so far, would really appreciate any help.

Generated keyStore and trustStore using keytool:

```
keytool -importcert -file /home/foo/server.crt -alias server_cert -keystore /home/foo/ca_truststore.jks -noprompt -storepass foo
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /home/foo/client.crt -inkey /home/foo/client_private_key.pem -out /home/foo/client.p12 -name client_cert -passout pass:foo
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass foo -destkeypass foo -destkeystore /home/foo/client_keystore.jks -srckeystore /home/foo/client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass foo -alias client_cert
```

Starting tomcat7 with these JVM settings

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/foo/ca_truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foo -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/foo/client_keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=foo -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS"
```

In my JAVA application code I queried the System property for trustStore and keyStore and I can see that they are same as the values I set above.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
String url = "https://x.x.x.x";
String data = "something to send";
String authStringEnc = "This is Base 64 encoded userid:pwd"; 
try {

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(data.toString());

    request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
}
```

---

### Exception that I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default HttpClient does not take system properties into account

Try replacing

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

with

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createSystem();
```